# Joins and Loops in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How to join the below tables to get result like in "Result" table:

Table: Invoice

```
Inv_No  Fk_Rep_ID       Inv_Date     Inv_Amt
3000              202       10/1/2014     35
3001              194       11/1/2014     40
3002              180       15/1/2014     55
```

Table :Return

```
Return_ID   FK_Rep_ID      Ret_Date Ret_Amt
2000              202     17/1/2014 67
2001        194   15/1/2015 43
```

Table: Credit

```
Credit_ID   FK_Rep_ID   credit_Date credit_Amnt
1000           NULL     4/2/2014    60
1001            202     5/2/2014    12
```

Table: Debit

```
Debit_ID    FK_Rep_ID         Debit_Date    Debit_Amnt
400           NULL         4/5/2014 600
4001              194          5/5/2014 110
```

Table:Receipt_Items

```
Fk_Rec_No   FK_Item_No     Item_Type    Rec_Item_ID 
7787             1000             2 1
7788             2000             1 1
7788             3000             0 2
7788             3001             0 3
7788             3002             0 4
7788             4000             3 5
7788             4001             3 6
7789             1001             2 1
```

Table :Sales_Rep

```
Rep_ID        Rep_Name
180         Vinu
194         Bibin
202         Salman
```

Result

```
Fk_Rec_No   Fk_Item_No  Item_Type   Rep_Name    Item_Date   Item_Amt
7787    1000    Credit  NULL    4/2/2014    -60
7788    2000    Return   salman 15/1/2014   -67
7788    3000    Invoice  salman 10/1/2014   35
7788    3001    Invoice  Bibin  11/1/2014   40
7788    3002    Invoice  Vinu   12/1/2014   55
7788    4000    Debit   NULL    4/5/2014    600
7788    4001    Debit   Bibin   5/5/2014    110
7789    1001    Credit  Salman  5/2/2014    -12
```

Query :

```
SELECT tt.*,SR.Rep_Name
    FROM(SELECT 
    fk_receipt_no
    ,fk_item_no
    ,CASE Item_type
    WHEN 0 THEN 'INVOICE'
    WHEN 1 THEN 'Return'
    WHEN 2 THEN 'Credit'
    WHEN 3 THEN 'Debit'
    END as ITEM_type,
    Case Item_type when 1 then '-'+Cast(Item_Amnt as varchar(50))
    when 2 then '-'+Cast(Item_Amnt as varchar(50))
    else Cast(Item_Amnt as varchar(50)) End Item_Amnt
    ,COALESCE(R.FK_Rep_ID,C.FK_Rep_ID,I.FK_Rep_ID)  as FK_Rep_ID
    ,COALESCE(R.Ret_Date,C.Note_Date,I.Inv_Date)  as Item_Date
    FROM Recp_Item RI LEFT JOIN [Return] R ON RI.FK_Item_no=R.Return_ID
    LEFT JOIN Credit C ON RI.FK_Item_No=C.Note_ID
    LEFT JOIN Invoice I ON RI.FK_Item_No=I.Inv_No
    ) tt LEFT JOIN [Sales Rep] SR ON SR.Rep_ID=tt.FK_Rep_ID
```

Comment: `to get result like in "Result" table:` where is it?

Comment: What result table? ^^

Comment: i can't post here my query , its having some formating error

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: I find your SQL to be completely illegible. Is there any scheme behind the formatting?

Comment: You need to describe the problem you are having.  How are the results your query is giving you different from your expected results? Or are you getting an error? If so what error?

Answer (score 2):

You probably should mention that FK_Item_No refers sometimes to different things, like Credit_ID.  **This kind of multipurpose FK *almost* always results in a union for each type of item it could represent.**

This is pseudo code, I expect you to provide all the tedious join criterias since you should be capable of doing so.

Notice left joins are used to the Rep table since you have some null FK's

In each select aliases are used to normalize the column names such as `credit_amnt` => `Item_Amt`.  Technically this is only required for the first select in the join so long as the others are in the same order, but I usually do it for all unions for readability.

```
Select * From
(
  Select ri.Fk_Rec_No, Credit_ID as Fk_Item_No, it.Name as Item_Type, 
    r.Rep_Name, c.credit_Date as Item_Date, c.credit_Amnt as Item_Amt
  From Credit c inner join Receipt_Items ri left join Rep r 
  --join with your item type table you don't show

    Union

  Select ri.Fk_Rec_No, Debit_ID as Fk_Item_No, it.Name as Item_Type, 
    r.Rep_Name, c.Debit_Date as Item_Date, d.Debit_Amnt as Item_Amt
  From Debit d inner join Receipt_Items ri left join Rep r 
  --join with your item type table you don't show

    Union
  ...

) as typesUnion
Order By Fk_Rec_No, Fk_Item_No
```